# Invoke Batch file in Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a scenario where we have many batch files(.bat) which run at specific interval of time. The Scripts start their invocation taking some valid data from the database and give some output as success, verified, into production etc. So I need to automate this using Java.

Any suggestions? Can I achieve this using Java?

I have tried:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("file path of exe or .bat files");
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103570/run-batch-file-from-java-code

Comment: What was the problem with what you have already tried?